# How to apply ternary operator for background-color style attribute in knockoutjs?

Tags: html, knockout.js

I need to apply background color in td element in table when there is some data in . If there's no data, I don't want any color. My code is as follows :

```
<td data-bind="text:EarlyOut,style:{background-color:EarlyOut!="" ? '#D2D6DE' : null}" ></td>
```

what do I write instead of null ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout is smart enough to not write `null` to the background color. **The issue with your code is the `-` character in the style property name.**

You either write `{ "background-color": ... }` or `{ backgroundColor: ... }`

Here's a runnable example that has this fix. Note that if `EarlyOut` is an observable property, you need the `()` to extract its value.

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  setColor: ko.observable(false)
});
```

```css
div {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: setColor() ? 'green' : null }">
  Hello world
</div>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: setColor">
  Overwrite color
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has more to do with CSS than knockout.js, you should write `'none'` (a string!) instead of `null`, at least if you want there to be no background color if your condition is `false`.